# Can I change the existing question to a new one?

Tags: support, etiquette, asking-questions

I have previously asked a question and got the answer but I not got another question which is based on the previous question. How do I post that, should I post another new one or edit the previous question and remove "accepted answer"?

Comment: Related: [edit and rephrase or ask new question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814/edit-and-rephrase-or-ask-new-question)

Comment: Also related: [question edited to change meaning](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2304/question-edited-to-change-meaning)

Answer (score 20):

Post a new one. There's no reason to remove the accepted answer; that's just unfair.

Comment: Okay, can I ask the answered person through "comment" option. posting the extended question??

Comment: @Surya: It would be better to post the new question separately and link to the old question.

Comment: Additionally, to mention the existence of the new question (and to link to it) in a comment to the old one seems a good idea.

Comment: It is often not easy to give an appropriate answer in a comment: not enough space. A new question is usually best.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Where does fairness come into it? Having a tick beside your answer doesn't somehow make it "more correct" or "better" than other answers. A correct answer is a correct answer whether it is accepted or not. The tick just makes it more convenient for people reading the question later (and anyway, better answers are usually reflected through the number of votes).

Comment: @user: you misinterpreted me. I mean that there's no reason to penalize the person whose answer you previously accepted because your _question is now different._ If your question is different, you should ask a different question, not take away points from the person who answered your old question.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I understand why you are saying: I just do not like the use of the words "penalise" and "unfair". I feel you are putting an emphasis on reputation, as if the whole point in being here is to bump up these points. (I doubt that is what you actually feel, and I don't disagree with the sentiment of your post, I just wanted to say that reputation isn't everything.)

Comment: @user: of course it's not everything, but it's _something._ It's easy to be disdainful of reputation, but that's ignoring the real psychological effect that it has on users in the aggregate.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Sure, but one or two questions are not going to make a difference.